# Facebook share button not displaying in Fancybox (Internet Explorer)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, facebook, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm rendering a share facebook button in a modal window (fancybox).

It's working well on Chrome and Firefox but I can't manage to make it work in IE 11.

The code looks to render exactly the same.

Here's what I have:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    var cultureInfo = '@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name';
    cultureInfo = (cultureInfo == "fr" ? "fr_FR" : "en_US");
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + cultureInfo + "/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

...

```
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="@(item.video == null ? "/Content/Image/Facteur/" + item.photo : item.video)" style="text-decoration: none;">
    </a>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <!-- my title for fancybox above-->
        <div class="fb-share-button coeurJumbotron" data-href="@Ressources.webAdress/facteur/FacteurStatic?Id=@item.Id" data-type="button_count" style="width:auto;"></div>
        <p class="lead"><h4 style="color:black;"><u><b>@item.prenom @item.nom</b></u></h4><h5 style="color:black;"><b>  @item.ville.nom, @item.ProvinceCulture</b></h5><h5 style="color:black;">@Ressources.wordBornIn @item.dob.Year</h5></p>
        <p class="lead"><h4 style="color:black;"><b>&laquo;</b>  @Html.Raw(item.commentaire.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />")) <b>&raquo;</b></h4></p>
    </div>
```

...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".fancybox").fancybox({

        beforeShow: function () {



            // set variable to next div element
            newTitle = $(this.element).next('div')
            // clone it with properties
            .clone(true, true)
            // change ID to avoid ID duplication
            .find("#demo").attr("id", "demo2").end()
             // change the target to new ID
            .find("#btnTranslate").attr("data-target", "#demo2").end()
            // show as html
            .html();

            // override fancybox title
            this.title = '<div class="myTitle">' + newTitle + '</div>';
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Any clue? Thanks!!

Comment: `newTitle = $(this.element).next('div')` seems to be missing a closing semicolon `;` ... and maybe you should add `.html();` to render the next `div`

Comment: Yeah my copy and paste error. The orginal code has the semicolon and the .html(). I edited the question.